# Hidden Backbone.js models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm playing around with backbone.js and have come to an impasse.  Here is my code:

```
window.Car = Backbone.Model.extend();
window.CarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend( {
    model: Car,
    url:"../api/car/",

});

window.CarListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'ul',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("reset", this.render);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        console.log(this.model);        //is an object
        console.log(this.model.models); //is an empty array

        return this;
    },
});

 // Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list",
        "cars/:id":"carDetails"
    },

    list:function () {
        this.carList = new CarCollection();
        this.carListView = new CarListView({model:this.carList});
        this.carList.fetch();
        $('#sidebar').html(this.carListView.render().el);
    },

});

$(function () {
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

I don't have enough reputation to post images, so here is the text version of the console from chrome developer tools:

```
V r {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _events: Object, constructor: function…}
    > _byId: Object
    > _events: Object
    > length: 4
    > models: Array[4]
    > __proto__: s
```

My issue is that I am trying to access the non-empty models property which seems to be "hidden" behind the empty one.  How do I access the models property that has a length of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a console quirk, but the core problem here is common - you are calling `.fetch()` (an asynchronous load) and then immediately calling `.render()`, expecting the data to be loaded. You need to wait until the data is loaded before you can access it - there are several ways to do this, but the easiest is probably to pass a `success` callback to `fetch`:

```
var carListView = this.carListView;
this.carList.fetch({
    success: function() {
          $('#sidebar').html(carListView.render().el);
    }
});
```

The console logs this oddly because when you call `console.log` when the collection is not yet loaded (showing `Array[0]`) but then inspect it manually after the load is complete (showing `Array[4]`).

Comment: thanks, two things: 1: that code results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: carListView is not defined`.  2: I thought binding on the 'reset' event would cause the render function to be called after the data is fetched?

Comment: 1. Whoops, you're right - see edit. You need to alias the view as a variable, as the `this` reference won't work in the callback. 2. The `reset` listener should work, but you're calling `carListView.render()` explicitly first, right after you call `.fetch()`.